# vitest returns 500 "Internal Server Error" for every nestjs route after switching from jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, vitest

I switched from jest to vitest and nestjs is throwing 500 server errors when the test was working previously with jest.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from '../../src/app.module';
import { it, beforeEach, describe } from 'vitest';
import request from 'supertest';

describe('/endpoint', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/endpoint').expect(200).expect(':)');
  });
});
```

Comment: didn't you got any stack trace to share? looks like something is broken in your app. Hard to tell why

Comment: What's the vitest config? Do you have `unplugin-swc` installed as a plugin for vitest?